# How to allow all file upload types except a specific one

Tags: php

My upload php code can allow all file types but i want to block out some certain file types 
here is my upload php code 
I want to block out file types like .exe,.php

please explain briefly I am a beginner in php

```
    <?php
$target_dir = "/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = filetype($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== true) {
        echo "THANK YOU - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}



// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you please explain briefly

Answer (score 0):

Core PHP(found on http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php):

```
// DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'] VALUE !!
// Check MIME Type by yourself.
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if (false === $ext = array_search(
    $finfo->file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']),
    array(
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
    ),
    true
)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
}
```

So Never trust `$_FILES['upfile']['mime']` always use `fileinfo`.